# тестирование компонента с декоратором

Tags: юнит-тесты, angular, jasmine, декоратор

В компоненте использую декоратор в котором задействован сервис:

```
@Component({...})
export class ExampleComponent {
    @exampleDecorator() private _field;
}

export function exampleDecorator() {
    return (target, property) => {
        const service = SomeModule.injector.get(ImportantService);

        Object.defineProperty(
            target.constructor.prototype,
            property,
            {
                enumerable: true,
                get: () => service.value
            }
         );
    };
}

@NgModule({...})
export class SomeModule {
    public static injector;
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        SomeModule.injector = injector;
    }
}
```

при тестировании, здесь

> SomeModule.injector.get

возникает ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

После нескольких попыток пришел к выводу, что декоратор загружается раньше чем тест.

Есть идеи как можно это протестировать? 
Или сама идея использовать сервис в декораторах не такая хорошая (или реализация)?

Comment: `injector.get(...)` нужно перенести непосредственно в `get` метод дескриптора, потому что фабрика, которую возвращает декоратор вызываются сразу, а модуль инстанциируется только в процессе `TestBed.configureTestingModule(...)`. И `Object.defineProperty(target, ...)` без `constructor.prototype` достаточно

Comment: да, спасибо. действительно сразу в ```get``` это лучше, чем моё решение

Answer (score 0):

решил, переделав декоратор:

```
export function exampleDecorator() {
    return (target, property) => {

        const selfClass = target.constructor.prototype;
        const randomName = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) + (new Date()).getTime();

        selfClass[randomName] = function() {
            return SomeModule.injector.get(ImportantService);
        }

        Object.defineProperty(
            selfClass,
            property,
            {
                enumerable: true,
                get: () => selfClass[randomName]().value
            }
         );
    };
}
```